# React native 0.14.2 Android images not showing

Tags: react-native

I've recently upgraded my version of React native to 0.14.2, and with that should come the easier use of images, located in one central folder. However for Android it's not working. The images show for my IOS app but on my Android app the images don't display at all. I don't get any errors so I know it has located the image. An example the code I am using is:
`

```
<Image
  style={{height:50,width:50}}
  source={require('./images/logo.png')}
  />
```

`
Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded, did you make sure that the react-native dependency in android/app/build.gradle was also updated to 0.14.+ ?

I found the [upgrade process](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html#content) to be rather flaky and so had to manually update the android dependencies on one project. I was experiencing similar issues up until that point.

Comment: I can't remember to be honest, but in my build.grade file my react native dependency display like this: `compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.14.+"`, any ideas?

Comment: I've just ran through the update process again and still no luck